# Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Tags: magento2.2, requirejs

I have created a custom `js` for customer add form. But I am getting the error "can not read property 'get' of undefined" in console.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

> Vendor/CustomCustomer/view/base/web/customercustom.js

```
define([
    "jquery",
    'jquery/ui',
    'underscore',
    'uiRegistry',
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select',
    'mage/url'
], function (_, uiRegistry, Select) {
    'use strict';

    return function (Select) {
        return Select.extend({
            initialize: function (value) {
                this._super();
                var customerCompany = uiRegistry.get('index = customer_company');
                var defaultCompany = uiRegistry.get('index = extension_attributes.company_attributes.company_id');
                var vessels = uiRegistry.get('index = customer_vessels');
                var customerUsername = uiRegistry.get('index = customer_username');
                var password = uiRegistry.get('index = password');
                var cnfpassword = uiRegistry.get('index = confirm_password');
                if (this.value() != 1) {
                    customerCompany.show();
                    defaultCompany.hide();
                    vessels.show();
                    customerUsername.show();
                    password.show();
                    cnfpassword.show();
                } else {
                    customerCompany.hide();
                    defaultCompany.show();
                    vessels.hide();
                    customerUsername.hide();
                    password.hide();
                    cnfpassword.hide();
                }
                return this;
            },
            onUpdate: function (value) {
                var customerCompany = uiRegistry.get('index = customer_company');
                var defaultCompany = uiRegistry.get('index = extension_attributes.company_attributes.company_id');
                var customerUsername = uiRegistry.get('index = customer_username');
                var password = uiRegistry.get('index = password');
                var cnfpassword = uiRegistry.get('index = confirm_password');
                if (value != 1) {
                    customerCompany.show();
                    defaultCompany.hide();
                    customerUsername.show();
                    password.show();
                    cnfpassword.show();
                } else {
                    customerCompany.hide();
                    defaultCompany.show();
                    customerUsername.hide();
                     password.hide();
                     cnfpassword.hide();
                }

                return this._super();
            },
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change position of jquery components in `define()` as below:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'uiRegistry',
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select',
    'jquery/ui',
    'mage/url'
], function ($, _, uiRegistry, Select) {
    'use strict';

    return function (Select) {
        return Select.extend({
            initialize: function (value) {
                this._super();
                var customerCompany = uiRegistry.get('index = customer_company');
                var defaultCompany = uiRegistry.get('index = extension_attributes.company_attributes.company_id');
                var vessels = uiRegistry.get('index = customer_vessels');
                var customerUsername = uiRegistry.get('index = customer_username');
                var password = uiRegistry.get('index = password');
                var cnfpassword = uiRegistry.get('index = confirm_password');
                if (this.value() != 1) {
                    customerCompany.show();
                    defaultCompany.hide();
                    vessels.show();
                    customerUsername.show();
                    password.show();
                    cnfpassword.show();
                } else {
                    customerCompany.hide();
                    defaultCompany.show();
                    vessels.hide();
                    customerUsername.hide();
                    password.hide();
                    cnfpassword.hide();
                }
                return this;
            },
            onUpdate: function (value) {
                var customerCompany = uiRegistry.get('index = customer_company');
                var defaultCompany = uiRegistry.get('index = extension_attributes.company_attributes.company_id');
                var customerUsername = uiRegistry.get('index = customer_username');
                var password = uiRegistry.get('index = password');
                var cnfpassword = uiRegistry.get('index = confirm_password');
                if (value != 1) {
                    customerCompany.show();
                    defaultCompany.hide();
                    customerUsername.show();
                    password.show();
                    cnfpassword.show();
                } else {
                    customerCompany.hide();
                    defaultCompany.show();
                    customerUsername.hide();
                     password.hide();
                     cnfpassword.hide();
                }

                return this._super();
            },
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. After making the abover mentioned changes now I am getting the error "Cannot read property 'show' of undefined".

Comment: it means selector on which you are using show() method is undefine, means you didnt get selector using uiRegistry

Comment: But it works on the second reload.